# Fast2sms not sending message to my mobile

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

currently i am working on an assignment with express.js and the assignment is i have to extract the information form req then i have send that data to a number in the form of message seems pretty easy right. And it sure is easy i have implemented the whole logic but message is not coming on my mobile. Its been 4 hours and i am still not able to figure what is wrong with my code. I have used an api fast2sms to send message

**HERE IS THE CODE**

```
const fast2sms = require('fast-two-sms');
app.post("/sendmessage", async(req,res)=>{
    try {
        const {client_email, client_name, income_per_month, savings_per_month, mobile_number} = req.body;
        var options = {
            authorization : process.env.API_KEY,
            message : 'hello',
            numbers : [mobile_number]
        } 
        const response = await fast2sms.sendMessage(options);
        res.send(response.message);
    } 
    catch (error) {
        res.send("Failed to send SMS to the client")
    }
})
```

When i send a post request it executed fine but we wierd thing is it is outputting message sent successfully i the terminal instead of sending it as response like in this image

[image]

**if i put console.log(req.body) in my app.js file the output looks like this**
[image]

i don't know what is wrong with it so please help me

Comment: Would it be possible to post whole response over here so we can review it and find the issue

Comment: As you said you are not getting error so we need to review the whole response so please log the response after sending SMS and post it over here

Comment: @SmitGajera i have updated the question now i have added the how the req and res both

Comment: is it working fine if you are trying to sent it from their portal and also look into dlt registration.

Comment: @Indraraj26 is it mandatory to do dtl registration to use API and whenever i try to make request it say first add 100 rupees into the account but the thing is i am already having 55 rupees in that account